# Jquery click function not responding

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright so for some reason whenever I try to click this input nothing happens, altho it should alert hello world...

```
<label>Ime Profesora</label><br/>
<input type='text' id='profesor_Ime' placeholder='Ime profesora...' /><br/>
<input type='submit' id='profesor_Submit' value='Dodaj Profesora'/>
```

And the JS

```
$("#profesor_Submit").click(function() {
        alert("Hello world");
    });
```

Here is the Jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/8y0hq6md/1/

EDIT: I am loading the form dynamically from the SQL, could that maybe be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Works fine when you add jQuery -> https://jsfiddle.net/8y0hq6md/2/

Comment: You need to include JQuery in that fiddle.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to include the Jquery into the code, altho one thing I suppose thats causing this is maybe because I am loading the form dynamically from the SQL or something? Not sure..

Comment: If you load something dynamically from ajax for example, you need to start searching from an element that is actually inside the DOM, for example: `$("body").on("click", "profesor_Submit", function() {`

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic With your last comment... [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) and/or [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the jQuery Library is included.

If that's already the case, also make sure that the document is "ready" by using `$(document).ready()`.

**Here's an example:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   // Your code here

});
```

..or the shorthand version:

```
$(function() {

   // Your code here

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not included jQuery library in your code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 

  $("#profesor_Submit").click(function() {
    alert("Hello world");
  });

});
```

```html
<label>Ime Profesora</label>
<br/>
<input type='text' id='profesor_Ime' placeholder='Ime profesora...' />
<br/>
<input type='submit' id='profesor_Submit' value='Dodaj Profesora' />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8y0hq6md/10/

Comment: Hmm weird, I have my JS included inside my HTML tho... But it still doesnt work, Im using 1.8.2 Jquery tho

Comment: in your personal code make sure you either run that snippet `onload` or that you include your JS file *AFTER*  the body content.

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic But do you have the jQuery library included in your HTML? Please post your complete HTML code.

Comment: @TomislavTomiNikolic It should still work with jQuery version 1.8.2. Please check my updated code.

Answer (score -1):

Okay so this was the solution

```
$(document.body).on('click', '#profesor_Submit' ,function(){
        alert("Hello world");
    });
```

This seems to work with it since I am loading the form dynamically

Comment: Going ahead, make sure to mention those details in your question so we all can help you better.